# Google Maps V3 - Override API KEY

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm loading Google Maps using the default script tag like the following

```
<script async defer
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
```

Is there a way to **override** this API_KEY after the page is loaded ? Or even create another instance of google maps without affecting the original instance?

This is needed for AB testing to avoid it from affecting the original API_KEY that is using throughout the website.

Iframe approach is probably not possible because it is needed to append several markers in the map.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone else has the same problem, first it is needed to reset the current instance of maps

```
google.maps = undefined;
```

Then you can just include your own script

```
var scriptNode = document.createElement('script');
scriptNode.src = GOOGLE_MAPS_URL_WITH_NEW_KEY;
document.head.append(scriptNode);
```

It works this way.

Note: If you have any other dependencies such as Infobox, you might need to add those again

Answer (score 0):

You can add edit your src attribute like this (jQuery) :

```
$("script").attr("src", YOUR_URL_HERE_WITH_AN_API_KEY_CHANGE);
```

Comment: hi, sorry about the delay. This would replace every script on the page.

Comment: yes, you must adapt for your code =) you can add other attributes to your script tag but it's not very SEO friendly